# Mysql: Using HAVING with other conditions instead of Multiple Self Join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join, having

I have a table that looks like this

```
ailment_symptoms 
+----+----------+-----------+
|id  |ailment_id|symptom_id |
+----+----------+-----------+
|1   | 1        |  1        |
|2   | 1        |  2        |
|3   | 2        |  1        |
|4   | 2        |  3        |
|5   | 3        |  3        |
|6   | 3        |  2        |
|7   | 4        |  1        |
|8   | 4        |  2        |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I wanted to select all ailment_id that had, say, `symptom_id=1 AND symptom id = 2` and some one suggested the code below.

```
SELECT s.ailment_id
FROM ailment_symptoms s
WHERE s.symptom_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY s.ailment_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.symptom_id) = 2
```

My issue now is, assuming the table has another column called `symptom_intesity` and i want to select an ailment id with 
`(symptom_id1 = 1 AND s1.symptom _intensity = 'acute') AND (symptom_id2 = 2 AND symptom_intensity='slight') AND (...) OR (...)`
like that. 
Using multiple self join, it will look something like this:

```
SELECT t1.ailment_id
FROM ailment_symptoms t1
INNER JOIN ailment_symptoms t2 ON t1.ailment_id = t2.ailment_id
INNER JOIN ailment_symptoms t3 ON t1.ailment_id = t3.ailment_id
INNER JOIN ailment_symptoms t4 ON t1.ailment_id = t4.ailment_id
   /*---- more inner joins as there are symptoms ----*/
WHERE (t1.symptom_id =  '1' AND t1.intensity = 'acute')
AND (t2.symptom_id =  '10')
AND (t3.symptom_id =  '3' AND t2.intensity = 'slight')
AND (t4.symptom_id =  '4')
 /*----and so on ----/
```

How do i achieve this using the structure of the first query. Please I will appreciate an explanation too, so I can be able to modify it to my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Note that id in the table above is redundant - and therefore, so is DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your goal correctly, I usually use concatenation in such cases, i.e. when the logical expression depend on some conditions:

```
     SELECT ailment_id
      FROM ailment_symptoms 
     WHERE symptom_id||symptom_intesity='1acute' OR symptom_id||symptom_intesity='2slight' OR symptom_id = '10' OR symptom_id =  '4'
    GROUP BY ailment_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT symptom_id) = 2
```